# Slider with breaks in between (discrete) for react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, slider

I have to create a slider with breaks at discrete value points eg: 0, 5, 10
Here's an example
[Slider Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8ZWt.png)

I'm not able to find any library that does this. I found one but it was for react web.
Does anybody have any experience with this or can point me in the right direction?

I need to create variants with Sliding at both ends (range), Discrete (mentioned above), and normal continuous slider. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Try to use this package npmjs.com/package/react-native-slider-picker (see the last example in docs)

Comment: I saw this but the github link isn't working. I'd have to make some modifications for my version. I guess the library is no longer open-sourced! @vac9

Comment: Try use this library @ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider (open source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-slider-picker)
Example in tutorial https://medium.com/@KPS250/custom-scale-slider-in-react-native-cb3e6ff786bd